# JavaScript Обучение, браузерные события, click

Tags: javascript, события

Изучаю JavaScript,браузерные события. Написал такой код:

```js
"use strict";

function hideInnerHtml() {
  var ulToggle = document.querySelector("#toggle");

  if (!clicker) {
    this.innerHTML = '▶ Сладости (нажми меня)!';
    ulToggle.classList.remove('hide');
    clicker = true;

  } else {
    this.innerHTML = '▼ Сладости (нажми меня)!';
    ulToggle.classList.add('hide');
    clicker = false;
  };
};

var clicker = false;

button.addEventListener('click', hideInnerHtml);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <button id="button">▼ Сладости (нажми меня)!</button>
  <ul id="toggle" class="hide">
    <li>Торт</li>
    <li>Пончик</li>
    <li>Пирожное</li>
  </ul>
```

У меня здесь замыкание на `clicker`, меня устраивает как работает данный код.

**Мой вопрос:**
Почему следующий код не работает как предыдущий(в моем понимании, они просто по-разному записаны)?

```js
"use strict";

function hideInnerHtml() {
  var ulToggle = document.querySelector("#toggle");

  if (!clicker) {
    this.innerHTML = '▶ Сладости (нажми меня)!';
    ulToggle.classList.remove('hide');
    clicker = true;
  };

  if (clicker) {
    this.innerHTML = '▼ Сладости (нажми меня)!';
    ulToggle.classList.add('hide');
    clicker = false;
  };
};

var clicker = false;

button.addEventListener('click', hideInnerHtml);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <button id="button">▼ Сладости (нажми меня)!</button>
  <ul id="toggle" class="hide">
    <li>Торт</li>
    <li>Пончик</li>
    <li>Пирожное</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: мне кажется, восклицательный знак должен быть внутри скобок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас выполняются оба условия.

Когда отрабатывает первый блок `if` переменная `clicker` становится `true` и потом срабатывает второй блок `if`.

Если вы добавите `return`, то все начнет работать.

```js
"use strict";

function hideInnerHtml() {
  var ulToggle = document.querySelector("#toggle");

  if (!clicker) {
    this.innerHTML = '▶ Сладости (нажми меня)!';
    ulToggle.classList.remove('hide');
    clicker = true;
    return;
  };

  if (clicker) {
    this.innerHTML = '▼ Сладости (нажми меня)!';
    ulToggle.classList.add('hide');
    clicker = false;
    return;
  };
};

var clicker = false;

button.addEventListener('click', hideInnerHtml);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <button id="button">▼ Сладости (нажми меня)!</button>
  <ul id="toggle" class="hide">
    <li>Торт</li>
    <li>Пончик</li>
    <li>Пирожное</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Все разобрался, благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (!clicker) {
    ...
    clicker = true;
  };
  // чему здесь _всегда_ равен clicker?
  if (clicker) {
    ...
    clicker = false;
  };
  // a здесь?
```

Вот как надо

```
  if (!clicker) {
    this.innerHTML = '▶ Сладости (нажми меня)!';
    ulToggle.classList.remove('hide');
  };
  if (clicker) {
    this.innerHTML = '▼ Сладости (нажми меня)!';
    ulToggle.classList.add('hide');
  };
  clicker = !clicker;
```

меняем значение `clicker` на противоположное только в одном месте - после проверки обоих условий.

Comment: Благодарю за ваш ответ! Я понял, что перезаписывает `clicker` и сразу выполняется второй блок, вариант с добавлением `return` мне понятен, но ваш второй код мне непонятен, возможно напишите полный код(мне в образовательных целях)?